# Java NumberFormat rounds incorrectly in "UP" mode

Tags: java, android, kotlin

This test fails:

```
@Test
fun testFormatRoundedUp() {
  val formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
  formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
  formatter.roundingMode = UP
  formatter.currency = Currency.getInstance("USD")
  val decimal = 1 / 100.toDouble()
  assertThat(formatter.format(decimal)).isEqualTo("$1")
}
```

Actual output is "$0". 
Is "UP" not the rounding mode I want here? AFAICT from the docs, it is.  `decimal` is `0.01` when I hook up the debugger, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.  I also tried non-Currency NumberFormat and it has the same behavior

Comment: Is this Java or another language?

Comment: @Compass Java. as stated in the title of the question and a tag

Comment: this sintax is kotlin, no?

Comment: oh, yeah, derp.

Comment: (but that shouldn't matter)

Comment: it shouldn't, but it might help to add the kotlin tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem is that `RoudingMode`:

> Each rounding mode indicates how the **least significant** returned digit of a rounded result is to be calculated.

So, in other words, `0.01` is being rounded to `0.1` (least significant digit is rounded)... And as you set `setMaximumFractionDigits` to `0`, all decimal digits are discarded leaving only the `0`

So, you must implement some logic to round the number twice if you want to round two less significant digits (or search how to do it... I'm currently searching now and I may update this answer later).

**Update**

It is possible to achieve what you want using `BigDecimal`. It supports this "recursive round" operation that you want. In java, your code would become:

```
@Test
public void testFormatRoundedUp() {
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
    formatter.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("USD"));

    double decimal = 1 / 100.0;
    BigDecimal decimalValue = new BigDecimal(decimal);

    Assert.assertThat("Format: 0.01", formatter.format(decimalValue.setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP)), equalTo("US$ 1"));
}
```